# How to serve an Image Pyramid to the front end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image-processing

I'm creating an image pyramid consisting of somewhere between 20-50 images in about 5 directories.  What's the best way to serve this to the front end?  Host the directories somewhere they can be referenced directly?  This doesn't seem secure at all.  Serve all 50 individually via an API?  This seems pretty unwieldy.  I'm not sure if that'll even work.  I believe they need to be in the directory structure to interact with the front end components anyway.  Is that possible?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question will vary depending on a number factors.

One way to set it up would be to just host the image files on your web server and use a cdn like cloudflare to cache the whole site. The cdn is crucial here because otherwise your assets can take a long time to load.

High level steps to set this up would be to configure a static directory from your node web server so that your assets can be accessed by the browser via a url like so: `http://localhost/static/images/image.png`

Assuming you're using webpack, you can use `file-loader` to simply `import` the image files like any other js file and use it in your react components. When you build the app, you can configure `file-loader` to automatically replace the references to the image file paths with that of your webpage's url.

Lastly, if you only have five directories of images, you could create 5 routes pertaining to each directory on your react app, and in each route, import the images that the route will show (ex. `import image from './static/images/image.png'` or `import * as images from './static/images/album'`), and render it (ex. `<img src={image} />` or loop through the images array and render each).

Comment: The specific number of files and directories is dynamic and will be generated not at 'build-time' but on demand as the front end uploads new images to create new pyramids of various size and resolution.